# I want to Get a list when clicking on regions of pie chart made by using plotly and rshiny package

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Need help... I had created a pie graph comparing count of car makes of US industry and Autongin(internal purpose). I want to get a list of car makes in autongin when clicking on autongin count(orange region in graph) and US make count when clicking on US count(blue region in graph).The Autongin make list contains 51 car makes and US make list contains 79 car makes.I created the graph using plotly package and the database is connected .I want to get the list of car makes of Autongin and US Industry. Now there is no change when clicking on the plot.

```
 The sample data is attached here


    AutonginMake    USMakename
1   Acura           Acura
2   Aston Martin    Aston Martin
3   Audi            Audi
4   Bentley         Bentley
5   BMW             BMW
6   Buick           Buick
7   Cadillac        Cadillac
8   Chevrolet       Chevrolet
9   Chrysler        Chrysler
10  Dodge           Dodge
11  Ford            Ford
12  GMC             GMC
13  Honda           Honda
14  HUMMER          Hummer
I took the count of above autonginmake and US make and polotted..My requirement is  to list this makes when clicking on corresponding regions of pie chart    


  #packages needed
    library(plotly)
    library(shiny)
    library(DBI)
    library(RMySQL)
    #connecting db
    dealerinventory1<-dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), user='ghhjjl', 
                                password='dfgfdgdg!', 
                                host='hfghfh', 
                                dbname='hhthhq23u')


    uscount1=dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,
                        'SELECT count(distinct makename) as USmakes FROM dealer_inventory.CarQuery;')

    autongincount1=dbGetQuery(dealerinventory1,
                              'SELECT count(distinct makename) as autonginmakes FROM dealer_inventory.car_inventory_json_lookup;')


    usandautongintable <- c(autongincount1,uscount1)
    usandautongintable
    label <- c(paste("Autongin Count: ", autongincount1),paste("US Industry Count: ", uscount1))
    label

    unlist <- as.numeric(unlist(usandautongintable))

    typeof(unlist)
    #table used for plotting
    table<- as.data.frame(usandautongintable)
    table
    #for plotting pie chart
    plotpie<- plot_ly(table, labels = label,values = unlist, type = "pie")  %>%
      layout(title = 'Comparison of Makes',
             xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

    plotpie

    library(shiny)
    library(plotly)


    ui= fluidPage(
        plotlyOutput("plot")
      )


    server1<- function(input,output){
      output$plot=renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(table, labels = label,values = unlist, type = "pie")  %>%
          layout(title = 'Comparison of Makes',
                 xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
                 yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
      })
    }

shinyApp(ui,server1)
```

Output plot link is here 
http://autonginreports.iinerds.com:3838/sample-apps/plot/

Comment: Can you make it to a small script that highlights the challenge?  The current one is not reproducible since people don't have access to the data.

Comment: My requirement is to  get a list as dropdown when clicking on regions of pie chart .In that pie chart, the orange region shows the count of Autongin car makes and the blue region shows the count of US car makes ...The plot link is attached here..http://autonginreports.iinerds.com:3838/sample-apps/plot/

Comment: Thanks for the data.  But the code is still not reproducible.  I suggest two things.  First, replace the part reading data from mysql by a script by code that defines variables inline (like `usmakes <- c("A", "B", "C")`).  This way people can simply run the code to get the same result.  Also, can you clarify what you mean by "list as dropdown"?  Do you want to create a `selectInput` or something dynamically?

Comment: Actually, My requirement is to get a list when clicking on graph.. please go through the link given below-

https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-map-click/



 In this graph,when we clicking on regions we get a set of data..In similiar way I want to get a list of car makes when clicking on my pie chart.

Comment: Please ignore "List as dropdown"..I want to get a list only ,when clicking on graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, hold the make names as variables.  Then, use `event_data` of plotly to catch which part of the pie has been clicked.
The make list is printed on a text output in the example, but you can use it in any way you want.

A good reference is here https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/linking-views-with-shiny.html.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(tagList(
  plotlyOutput("pie"),
  verbatimTextOutput("makes")
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  # dummy makes data
  usmakes <- c("ford", "acura", "bmw")
  autonginmakes <- c("cadillac", "hummer")
  usmakes_count <- length(usmakes)
  autonginmakes_count <- length(autonginmakes)

  output$pie <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(labels=c("US", "Autongin"), 
            values=c(usmakes_count, autonginmakes_count),
            key=c("us", "autongin"),
            type="pie")
  })

  output$makes <- renderPrint({
    clicked <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (is.null(clicked)) {
      "no selection"
    } else if (clicked$key == "us") {
      usmakes
    } else {
      autonginmakes
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It's working..Thank You..now one more doubt ...If I want to drill down into the list,means when  I click on  the make FORD I want to get a list of models  of ford.
Similiarly,if I get a list of 5 car models of FORD as,FIGO,FIESTA,ECOSPORT,ENDEAVOUR,ICON,,from this models ,I select FIGO,then I want to get a list of colour variations available for FIGO..In this manner I want to drill down ...Is there any option? please share...

Comment: I am sure you can.  We need more detailed app design, since there is no component to click FORD in the current app.  Also, how do you want to drill down?  Maybe on `selectInput`?  How do you want to list the color variations?  
With these details, I believe you can implement what you want.
Since this is a bit off the topic of this question, it will be better to make another question if you go further.